# Why does the equality operator not work on three conditions?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I've been wanting on doing something very simple and ran into this, which I don't understand why:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a var1=10
set /a var2=10
set /a var3=10

:test1
if %var1%==%var2% (
    if %var2%==%var3% (
        echo This Works
        pause
    )
)

:test2
if %var1%==%var2%==%var3% (
    echo But this does not
    pause
)
```

In this case, the  `test1` label works perfectly but the `test2` label doesn't work.

Can anyone help me understanding why?

Comment: `if "%var1%"=="%var2%" if "%var1%"=="%var3%" ( … )` will do it. You should generally quote both sides of comparison expressions unless they are numeric…

Comment: It does not work because `cmd` does not support this kind of expression. One relational operator shall be the number. The number shall not be two, nor shall the number be three. The number of relational operators shall be one.

Comment: As an aside, the following commands are also not technically correct, `set /a var1=10`, `set /a var2=10`, and `set /a var3=10`. The `Set` command with the `/A` option performs arithmetic, but you aren't performing any. All variables are of the type string, so please do not think that using the `/A` option magically creates an integer type value. What you should have used is `set "var1=10"`, `set "var2=10"`, and `set "var3=10"` to properly define those variables. If your actual variables are set elsewhere, and you've only used those for a [mcve], you could have used `Set /A var1=var2=var3=10`.

Comment: When searching for how to accomplish this task I sure would like to know where on the Internet you found information that you could even attempt to do that type of syntax with a batch file.  A quick read of the help file for the `IF` command would have easily answered your question.   Open up a command prompt and type: `IF /?1`.  You can also find all the syntax information on Microsoft's site. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc754340(v=ws.11)

Comment: Try: `if "%var1%%var2%" == "%var2%%var3%" ( ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the help of the [`if` command](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) (type `if /?`), you can only compare two expressions but not three.

However, you could concatenate multiple comparisons:

```cmd
if %var1% equ %var2% if %var2% equ %var3% (
    rem // Do something...
)
```

This is a short form of the following (which becomes particularly relevant as soon as you want to use `else` clauses):

```cmd
if %var1% equ %var2% (
    if %var2% equ %var3% (
        rem // Do something...
    )
)
```

---

In the above I used the `equ` operator rather than `==` since you are comparing integers.
If you want to compare strings, use `==`, together with quotation (to avoid issues with empty strings and to protect special characters):

```cmd
if "%var1%"=="%var2%" if "%var2%"=="%var3%" (
    rem // Do something...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

No knowledge of batch, but I can share context from some other programming languages where this typically doesn't work.

This will likely parse as either:

- `(%var1% == %var2%) == %var3%`, or
- `%var1% == (%var2% == %var3%)`.

In either case, one of the equalities between two variables is evaluated first, resulting in a `false` or `true` that will probably not be equal to the third variable (even if it does happen to, that's probably not what you want).

The solution is to use two seperate equalities, conjuncted with an AND operator, like `%var1%==%var2% AND %var2%==%var3%`

Comment: Sadly, batch doesn't have `AND` or `OR`, but you're correct that `if %var1%==%var2%==%var3%` is invalid. You can chain two `if`s together like `if "%var1%"=="%var2%" if "%var2%"=="%var3%"` but that's it.

Comment: There is no concept of TRUE/FALSE in `cmd`'s `if`. It's merely `if STRING1 <comparator> STRING2 <command>`

Comment: @SomethingDark What a mess lol. Anyway, you should write that up into an answer! I'll up vote it and delete my guess